# Convert string to another encoding

Tags: c#, encoding

I´m trying parse subject from email.

My subject look like this: `RE:_Nedoru=E8en=E1_z=E1silka_k_pojistn=E9`
and I need to convert it to right encoding so final string will look like this:
`Nedoručená zásilka k pojistné smlouvě`

This is my method:

```
private static string GetByOwnSubject(string file)
    {
        byte[] soubor1Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file).Take(5000).ToArray();//Read part of file where is subject
        file = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1250).GetString(soubor1Byte);//Convert subject to string
        string subject = ExtractSubject(file.Substring(file.IndexOf("Subject: "))).Substring(3);//In this part I substract subject by 
        //regex(subject look like this = "RE:_Nedoru=E8en=E1_z=E1silka_k_pojistn=E9";)
        return subject;
    }
```

My question is how to convert it to right format?
Sory for my english.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding. You can for example use [MimeKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MimeKit/) to decode it.

Comment: Ok so I need to convert from MIME to my encoding by my own or by extern library?